# call gui from JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, user-interface

I am currently learning JSP and Java Servlets.  I was wondering if there is any way to call a java GUI from a JSP, not necessarily to load into the page, but to load onto the screen for database input.  I am struggling trying to find some reference on how to do this on the net, but no luck so far.

Comment: Do you mean calling a Swing application on the server side or do you mean calling an application on user's (client) desktop?

Comment: You can't really accomplish anything different than you would having the client download the application separately.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/index.html

Comment: But why not just taking input via a HTML form like everyone else?

Comment: as @BalusC has said , as you are a starter in jsp and servlets , i think the thing you are looking for is html inputs and form only

Answer (score 0):

You could use Java Webstart to start up the application on the client side.  Or, ask the user to install a local client differently (like a daemon service).

The "GUI application" must have some kind of RPC (=remote procedure call) service running in background.

Once the client has your gui application installed, the JSP can invoke urls on `http://localhost:port` (ajax would help sending messages to the GUI application). The GUI application must have some rpc system (rest, webservice) that receives the requests from your web application (your jsp app) and start the GUI requested by the URL.
The problem here is to make sure the client has the port of choice available.

Another possibility is to register some URL to your application in the client side, so that when the user clicks a url like `myapp://form/123` the OS automatically invokes your application to handle that URL. This kind of thing must be done differently per operating system. It's the way it works when you click on a magnet link or a `skype://link`. The procedure to register urls in the operating system is different per OS, you need to do some research (I never did that, but I am sure it is possible). You can also register a file extension to your app, and make sure that the specified extension is registered to your app. When the browser downloads the file and opens it, your app is invoked with the file downloaded as parameter (which will contain the instruction for your GUI). But most browser will not start automatically the app associated to the file after the download: again, you need to do some tricks on the client's operating system to make the "download and open" the default behavior for the browser.

Comment: Apologies, I should have been more thorough on what I am trying to do.  I am looking to launch a simple GUI that a few folks will have access to via username and password GUI, enter in some things, and then have it print out on the web page.  My gui is linked up to a database and can successfully do all the CRUD.  Now all I basically have to do is link it up with the web application.  Didn't know if this could be done or if you had to dynamically connect the DB using the servlets.